# Is it possible to improve the process of instance creation/deletion in Django using querysets?

Tags: django, django-queryset

So I have a list of unique pupils (pupil is the primary_key in an LDAP database, each with an associated teacher, which can be the same for several pupils.

There is a box in an edit form for each teacher's pupils, where a user can add/remove an pupil, and then the database is updated according using the below function. My current function is as follows. (`teacher` is the teacher associated with the edit page form, and `updated_list` is a list of the `pupil`s' names what has been submitted and passed to this function)

```
def update_pupils(teacher, updated_list):

    old_pupils = Pupil.objects.filter(teacher=teacher)
    for pupils in old_pupils:
        if pupil.name not in updated_list:
            pupil.delete()
        else:
            updated_list.remove(pupil.name)
    for pupil in updated_list:
        if not Pupil.objects.filter(name=name):
            new_pupil = pupil(name=name, teacher=teacher)
            new_pupil.save()
```

As you can see the function basically finds what was the old pupil list for the teacher, looks at those and if an instance is not in our new updated_list, deletes it from the database. We then remove those deleted from the updated_list (or at least their names)...meaning the ones left are the newly created ones, which we then iterate over and save.

Now ideally, I would like to access the database as infrequently as possible if that makes sense. So can I do any of the following?

In the initial iteration, can I simply mark those pupils up for deletion and potentially do the deleting and saving together, at a later date? I know I can bulk delete items but can I somehow mark those which I want to delete, without having to access the database which I know can be expensive if the number of deletions is going to be high...and then delete a lot at once?

In the second iteration, is it possible to create the various instances and then save them all in one go? Again, I see in Django 1.4 that you can use `bulk_create` but then how do you save these? Plus, I'm actually using Django 1.3 :(...

I am kinda assuming that the above steps would actually help with the performance of the function?...But please let me know if that's not the case.

I have of course been reading this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/ So I have a list of unique items, each with an associated email address, which can be the same for several items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in this line

```
if not Pupil.objects.filter(name=name):
```

It looks like the `name` variable is undefined no ?

Then here is a shortcut for your code I think:

```
def update_pupils(teacher, updated_list):
    # Step 1 : delete
    Pupil.objects.filter(teacher=teacher).exclude(name__in=updated_list).delete() # delete all the not updated objects for this teacher

    # Step 2 : update
      # either
    for name in updated_list:
        Pupil.objects.update_or_create(name=name, defaults={teacher:teacher}) # for updated objects, if an object of this name exists, update its teacher, else create a new object with the name from updated_list and the input teacher
      # or (but I'm not sure this one will work)
    Pupil.objects.update_or_create(name__in=updated_list, defaults={teacher:teacher})
```

Another solution, if your Pupil object only has those 2 attributes and isn't referenced by a foreign key in another relation, is to delete all the "Pupil" instances of this teacher, and then use a bulk_create.. It allows only 2 access to the DB, but it's ugly

**EDIT:** in first loop, `pupil` also is undefined